# Instagram shows non-followed people in my feed

Tags: instagram

I logged on to my Instagram account for the first time in a year or two. I never really used it much. I only remember following 7 or 8 close friends. When I logged in, I was following over 2000+ people. I don't know how, my children may have gotten on my phone and accidentally followed people a bunch over time not knowing what they were doing. I dunno.

Anyways, after taking a long time to slowly unfollow everyone, my Following list now only shows the 8 friends that I originally wanted to follow. However, on my profile screen it still says I am following 313 people. Even though only my 8 friends appear in my following list. What is going on here?

Also, on my feed, it shows mostly pictures from people that I am not following. Random strangers. How do I turn this off? I just want to see pics from the 8 friends I am following.

Comment: How many followers do you see on your profile in instagram? I think that is the best number to check for correct amount of followers.

Comment: On my profile page, I see 314 Following (I followed another friend since making this post). When I click this, it only shows 8 people. Those 8 people are the correct people I want to follow though. It's just that profile says I'm following 314 people... Pretty stupid that Instagram has no support email or phone number. Really ridiculous.